# How to set up SDDM and PAM to cooperate on blocking some logins?

Tags: pam, sddm

In short - I've read few topics and articles and I can't get PAM to work with SDDM (I'm using Ubuntu+XFCE4+SDDM)

I've modified /etc/security/time.conf file to this

```
login ; * ; aaaa ; Wk1900-2000
login ; * ; aaaa ; Wd1400-2200
```

Then - I un-commented in /etc/pam.d/common-auth this line :

```
account requisite   pam_time.so
```

(later I changed requisite to require, because.. I don't know what it means, but in almost any topic I read, people mentioned "account require pam_time.so")

then I tried it out in tty2. I could log into my main account, and I wasn't able to log into aaaa account (exactly as expected)

But - when I go graphically through SDDM I can log in with any account (including "aaaa" account).

(I do have in mind to actually look at what hour it is. Last test it was is (Wednesday) 23:55 and I'm trying since ~22:15 (so after 22, even if I messed up weekend and weekday, or whatever those aliases mean in time.conf) )

I also added "account required pam_time.so" to /etc/pam.d/common-account , because.. I don't know why it was supposed to be in common-auth and not in common-account (now I keep it in both those files).

I found in pam.d file called sddm. From what I understand it includes common-auth
(it contains line : "@include common-account")
but, I added "account required pam_time.so" line here anyway and it caused no change.

I was testing 1 hundred different logical and semi-logical ideas, so at one time I added (to /etc/pam.d/SDDM) line :

```
auth required pam_time.so
```

At first I thought it worked - because it restricted "aaaa" login, but later I realized it doesn't work, because no-one can login. (I guess, SDDM just "broke", because I did something stupid). After going to tty and un-doing this change I was able to log through SDDM again.

But it gave me hint that SDDM file indeed influences SDDM at least in *some* way... I re-added and keept "account required" in SDDM file during further tries, but  no matter what I did (I was changing time.conf file and adding/removing this "account req..." line to/from many files. It still doesn't work. Maybe I should do some change in some other file inside /etc/pam.d/?

My pam.d folder contains these files :

```
ls /etc/pam.d/
chfn                                   lightdm-autologin
chpasswd                               lightdm-greeter
chsh                                   login
common-account                         newusers
common-account.pam-old                 other
common-auth                            passwd
common-auth.pam-old                    polkit-1
common-password                        ppp
common-password.pam-old                runuser
common-session                         runuser-l
common-session-noninteractive          samba
common-session-noninteractive.pam-old  sddm
common-session.pam-old                 sddm-autologin
cron                                   sddm-greeter
cups                                   su
gdm-autologin                          sudo
gdm-fingerprint                        su-l
gdm-launch-environment                 systemd-user
gdm-password                           xfce4-screensaver
gnome-screensaver                      xscreensaver
lightdm
```

I do believe my time.conf works correctly, because ... logging into tty works very much as expected.

I don't know what SDDM does, that it doesn't work.

I've been looking at all of those topics/sites
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SDDM
https://www.stephenrlang.com/2012/06/using-pam-to-enforce-access-based-on-time/
https://www.techrepublic.com/article/using-pam-to-restrict-access-based-on-time/
https://linux.die.net/man/5/pam.d
https://www.stephenrlang.com/2012/06/using-pam-to-enforce-access-based-on-time/
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=258195
+some others

and... Either I'm too stupid to understand what I just read, or all of those sites still don't contains information that I need.